# Is there a "non-curved" manifold?

Tags: manifolds

I've seen some visualizations of manifolds. It seems that they are all **"curved"** shapes. Is there a **"non-curved"** manifold?

[image: 2D manifolds]

Comment: Why not plain (plane?) old $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: There are no compact manifolds that can be represented in Euclidean space as non-curved. But remove the “compact” condition, any connected open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is a “flat” manifold.

Comment: (All of the pictured manifolds are compact.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you share an intuitive explanation of "compact" regarding to manifolds?

Comment: Indeed there are two versions of "curved" manifolds. One intrinsic and one extrinsic. The "torus" $\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$ in $\mathbb R^4$ is not curved intrinsically.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can get a flat, compact manifold embedded in $\Bbb R^3$. This is a consequence of the [Nash embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem). In particular, a couple of years ago, this was [done in practice](https://www.emis.de/journals/em/images/pdf/em_24.pdf)  with a torus, and the results are quite visually interesting. Here are the first three steps in the construction:

[image: corrugations]

It may look curved, but it does actually give a $C^1$ isometric embedding of the flat torus $S^1\times S^1$ in three-dimensional Euclidean space. ($C^1$, i.e. continuously differentiable, is important because otherwise distances along the surface are not necessarily well-defined.)

Comment: You should point out that $C^1$ is the essential thing here.

Comment: @ArcticChar You're right. Done.

Comment: I think the main point is that there does not exists $C^3$ embedded flat surface in $\mathbb R^3$. Your answer is so technical for someone who do not even know what compact means.